# How to use DataBindings property properly?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm attempting to bind a windows form label to a variable. when i run that code lable1 was displayed as 50 but when i increment using button1 it doesn't change to 51. here is my attemp

```
    int x = 50;
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "X", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        X++;
    }
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your data in another class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged so that the UI will be notified and updated:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataClass dc;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dc = new DataClass();
        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dc, "X", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dc.X++;
    }
}

public class DataClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int x = 50;
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            x = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. can i use this on a static class. and can i use variable instead of a property?

Comment: I don't see a way to use a static class. The data binding needs an object instance for the `Add()` method. you must use a property with `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0):

```
    int X = 50;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = X.ToString();            
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        X += 1;
        label1.Text = X.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Class Form must be implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, like this:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        int x = 50;
        public int X
        {
            get { return x; }
            set { x = value; OnPropertyChanged("X"); }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "X", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            X++;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
}
```